# TFS 2010 - Access Denied to Administrator for '/tfs'

Tags: tfs

I'm trying to set up a TFS2010 (with SP1) server and I keep running into hurdles.

The latest prevents me from doing anything useful as every HTTP request to "https://tfs.myserver.com/tfs" results in a HTTP 401. It doesn't matter if these requests come from the TFS Administration Console or from a web-browser. Every time I'm prompted to authenticate I enter the domain Administrator's fully-qualified username and password and I always get this error message:

```
Team Foundation Server
TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://tfs.myserver.com/tfs. - The remote erver returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

Only a few settings in the Administration Console work (such as "Change URLs") but others, like "Group Membership" (either on the Application Tier node or on a Team Project Collection) results in the same prompt-then-fail.

The SSL certificate is valid, and the URLs seem consistent. I can't think what I'm missing out on.

EDIT: There is nothing relevant in the usual Event Logs. The Security log does show my Audit Failures, but I don't understand them because I'm entering the usernames and passwords correctly (the very same I use to access the servers over RDP):

```
An account failed to log on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       -
    Account Domain:     -
    Logon ID:       0x0

Logon Type:         3

Account For Which Logon Failed:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       Administrator
    Account Domain:     DOMAIN

Failure Information:
    Failure Reason:     Unknown user name or bad password.
    Status:         0xc000006d
    Sub Status:     0xc000006a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After growing frustrated with trying the helpful suggestions people made but not getting anywhere I decided to start-over and try again. I completely uninstalled TFS, SQL Server, and SharePoint services and reinstalled from scratch.

This time it worked fine - no meddling with security was necessary and the system just worked out-of-the-box.

Looking back, I think the problem was that I set-up TFS with the advanced option to use SharePoint, and then I probably fiddled around with settings I wasn't familar with and ended up making a hash of things.

Note to future self: practice in a VM before deploying in production.

Answer (score 2):

What's different about Group Membership & security dialogs is they go through the client APIs and access via IIS.  All others such as change server urls go through the server model straight to the DBs.  That means IIS cannot authenticate on your domain for some reason ...

From the description, it seems like a domain joined machine.  Does IIS have access to the domain controllers? (is it connected to the domain network)  The wizards verify you can reach AD but if you disconnect afterwards ... If IIS can't reach AD it will not be able to authenticate.  TFS relies on IIS for windows authentication.  It appears it can't do that.

Some other things to try:

1. On the application tier panel of the admin console, try changing the account (domain account) that the server runs as.
2. Did  you choose Kerberos authentication in the advanced wizard?  If you do that with a domain user as the service account, there's a pop-up dialog telling you that you need extra AD administration.  If you did that, you can change to NTLM from the admin console.
3. Try to access it via http://machinename:8080/tfs (instead of FQDN) both locally and remotely.  Try http://machinename:8080/tfs/web from the web browser as well.  make sure you're not having a proxy server issue (routing NTLM through proxy servers can be problematic - if you have bypass local in IE settings then address without dots won't route through the proxy and takes that out of the troubleshooting picture).  You can also completely disable proxy in IE just for troubleshooting.
4. Create another web site manually with a hello world aspx running as the same account with anonymous & basic auth disabled and integrated windows auth enabled.  Ensure it works.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I'm afraid none of those worked. I solved it by uninstalling everything and starting from scratch.